# Changing the Grid Size in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am just trying to add 3 centered vertical buttons to a GridBagLayout in java swing.  Right now I believe the default grid size is 3x3.  I wanted to know if I can change that and add more columns and rows.  I simply want to make 3 centered equally spaced butons in a pane.

```
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
    // Insert a space before the first button
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++ ){
        pane.add(new JLabel(""));
    }
    pane.add(new Button("1"));
    pane.add(new Button("2"));
        pane.add(new Button("3"));
    // Insert a space after the last button
    pane.add(new JLabel(""));
```

That was the final solution Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why does it have to be a GridBagLayout? A GridLayout with one column and three rows sounds perfectly right for you.

Comment: +1 for great progress in last day(s)

Comment: Glad you found what you are looking for on SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Chris a `GridLayout` would be easier:

```
myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
// Insert a space before the first button
add(new JLabel(""));
add(new Button("1"));
add(new Button("2"));
add(new Button("3"));
// Insert a space after the last button
add(new JLabel(""));
```

Comment: I need the buttons to be white space above the first button and below the last button.  I tried the GridLayout and couldn't get this effect.  I need buttons at (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2)

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz This can be achieved by inserting empty labels there. Please see my edit.

Comment: +1 for nicer output would be better to add Gap betweens JComponents e.g. `myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1, 10, 10));`

Answer (score 4):

Simply add more values to the weights attributes. This tells it how to lay out the gridbag - 0 means use only the space needed, then the rest of the space is split up according to the weights given.

```
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
...
gbl.columnWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gbl.rowWeights = new double[] {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
...
contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);
```

And then give your items `GridBagConstraints` with `gridx` and `gridy` set appropriately (from 0) for the new columns/rows:

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
...
gbc.gridx = 3;
gbc.gridy = 3;
...
contentPane.add(textFieldName, gbc_textFieldName);
```